# Accessing gem methods in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created my own gem. It is a very basic gem with only a 'hi' method in it. In the lib directory of my gem I have 'mygem.rb' file which has the above method.

Now I have created a simple rails app which is trying to use this method.
So how should I use it?

I tried to do something like this:-

In my app/controllers I have a file named hello_controller.rb which looks like this...

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @message= mygem.hi 
        @count=3
        @bonus="This message came from the controller."
    end
end
```

But on my localhost it is giving me the following error:
NameError in HelloController#index

uninitialized constant HelloController::mygem

Please solve this error..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the gem to the Gemfile.

You can use something like this:
`gem 'mygem', path: 'path/to/gem'`

It is also a good idea to wrap your gem code in a class or module so it should be:

`lib/mygem.rb`

```
class MyGem
  def self.hi
    'Hi there!'
  end
end
```

You then call it in your controller as `MyGem.hi`

Comment: I updated my Gemfile with this gem and the required path. My gem code is present exactly in lib/mygem.rb as you indicated. But for some reason its giving this error.

Comment: you may need to require 'mygem'. Also, try getting it working from irb first

Comment: I tried getting it working from irb and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bundler then:

Create a gem:

```
bundle gem my_gem
```

Build the gem:

```
gem build my_gem.gemspec
```

Install the gem:

```
gem install my_gem-0.0.1.gem
```

Add the gem to the Gemfile of your rails app

```
gem 'my_gem'
```

Add to the gem bundle

```
bundle
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same as you said. Now I am trying to access the method as shown: @message= mygem.hi but it is giving me error.